# How to get a list of indexes selected by a specific value efficiently with numpy arrays?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array like this:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([9, 6, 3, 8, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 9, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

And I want to get a list of indexes of the found values by groups

```
index_list_2 = [4 ]         # index list of the element with the value 2
index_list_3 = [2, 5, 6 ]
index_list_4 = [7, 8 ]
index_list_9 = [0, 9, 17]

# [...]
```

The first approach that comes to my mind (that´s not very pythonic):

```
i = 0
for x in arr:
    if x == 2:
        index_list_2 += [i]
    if x == 3:
        index_list_3 += [i]
    if x == 4:
        index_list_4 += [i]
    if x == 9:
        index_list_9 += [i]
    i += 1
```

Which is the most efficient way to achieve this with numpy arrays?

Comment: Although this is not numpy, combining `itertools.groupby` and `enumerate` would work.

Comment: Is `arr` always sorted?

Comment: @hpaulj no, as you can see there is a 9 is in the middle of the array as well. I have added more numbers to avoid the misunderstanding

Comment: There's nothing inherently array-like about this problem - it's really about collecting positions in a list.  Your result is lists of varying length which is a good indicator that this doesn't have a fast numpy solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should not be too slow. The array is iterated only once.
The result (ind) is a dictionary value -> list of indexes.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 9, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9])

ind = dict()
for i, val in enumerate(arr):
  ind.setdefault(val, []).append(i)
```

Comment: `collections.defaultdict` shortens the last line to `dd[val].append(i)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to find all the unique values and [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to find their indexes:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 9, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9])

# get the unique values
unique_arr = np.unique(arr)

# loop through the unique numbers and find the indeces
indexes_value = {}
for num in unique_arr:
    indexes = np.where(arr == num)[0]
    indexes_value[num] = indexes  # or list(indexes) if you prefer
```

Now you have a dictionary of indexes of each value and you can assign what you want to your `index_list_*` lists.

Answer (score 2):

Might not be the fastes but a oneliner with numpy would be:

```
index_dict = {v: np.flatnonzero(arr == v) for v in np.unique(arr)}
```