# Retrieve indexes of multiple values with Numpy in a vectorization way

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

In order to get the index corresponding to the "99" value in a numpy array, we do :

```
mynumpy=([5,6,9,2,99,3,88,4,7))
np.where(my_numpy==99)
```

What if, I want to get the index corresponding to the following values 99,55,6,3,7? Obviously, it's possible to do it with a simple loop but I'm looking for a more vectorization solution. I know Numpy is very powerful so I think it might exist something like that.

desired output :

```
searched_values=np.array([99,55,6,3,7])
np.where(searched_values in mynumpy)
[(4),(),(1),(5),(8)]
```

Comment: check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32191029/getting-the-indices-of-several-elements-in-a-numpy-array-at-once

Comment: @Kasramvd Re-opening because this question additionally needs the masking for the elements that are not present in `searched_values`. Hope that looks fair.

Comment: Yeah Divakar's solution takes into account the special case where values are not present

Comment: Can there be multiple values?

Comment: A similar question involving multiple values, [How to get a list of indexes selected by a specific value efficiently with numpy arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48686381/how-to-get-a-list-of-indexes-selected-by-a-specific-value-efficiently-with-numpy).  The accepted answer used a default dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach with `np.searchsorted` -

```
def find_indexes(ar, searched_values, invalid_val=-1):
    sidx = ar.argsort()
    pidx = np.searchsorted(ar, searched_values, sorter=sidx)
    pidx[pidx==len(ar)] = 0
    idx = sidx[pidx]
    idx[ar[idx] != searched_values] = invalid_val
    return idx
```

Sample run -

```
In [29]: find_indexes(mynumpy, searched_values, invalid_val=-1)
Out[29]: array([ 4, -1,  1,  5,  8])
```

For a generic invalid value specifier, we could use `np.where` -

```
def find_indexes_v2(ar, searched_values, invalid_val=-1):
    sidx = ar.argsort()
    pidx = np.searchsorted(ar, searched_values, sorter=sidx)
    pidx[pidx==len(ar)] = 0
    idx = sidx[pidx]
    return np.where(ar[idx] == searched_values, idx, invalid_val)
```

Sample run -

```
In [35]: find_indexes_v2(mynumpy, searched_values, invalid_val=None)
Out[35]: array([4, None, 1, 5, 8], dtype=object)

# For list output
In [36]: find_indexes_v2(mynumpy, searched_values, invalid_val=None).tolist()
Out[36]: [4, None, 1, 5, 8]
```

Comment: Waou, thks a lot, indeed it looks like to another question, but you take into account special cases so I do not know what to do.

Comment: @hansglick Not sure what you meant by - "do not know what to do" thing :)

Comment: Just see your stackoverflow profile, how can I send you a private message?

Comment: What if it the element is present several times. I would like to be able to retrieve all the indexes. find_indexes(np.array([5,11,5]),np.array([5])) . Desired output [(0,2)]

Comment: @hansglick, you should have included some duplicates in the original question.