# Vectorized groupby with NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

Pandas has a widely-used [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) facility to split up a DataFrame based on a corresponding mapping, from which you can apply a calculation on each subgroup and recombine the results.

Can this be done flexibly in NumPy without a native Python for-loop?  With a Python loop, this would look like:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> X = np.arange(10).reshape(5, 2)
>>> groups = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1])

# Split up elements (rows) of `X` based on their element wise group
>>> np.array([X[groups==i].sum() for i in np.unique(groups)])
array([15, 30])
```

Above 15 is the sum of the first three rows of `X`, and 30 is the sum of the remaining two.

By "flexibly,” I just mean that we aren't focusing on one particular computation such as sum, count, maximum, etc, but rather passing any computation to the grouped arrays.

If not, is there a faster approach than the above?

Comment: Note, `itertools.groupby` doesn't function like `pandas.Dataframe.groupby`, unless the iterable you pass to `itertools.groupby` is sorted by the grouping key...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Right ... and the `key` parameter for itertools needs to be a callable (not an array of groups).  And you couldn't use something like `groups.__getitem__` because it needs to be a function that gets applied to each element of the first arg

Comment: Do you have any idea of how pandas implements the groupby?  Does it use Python structures (dictionary?  itertools groupby?), C or Cython code?  The itertools version groups contiguous groups, runs.  So the input (key) has to be sorted.

Comment: It's a bit like the binning problem here: [How to get a list of indexes selected by a specific value efficiently with numpy arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48686381).  I've argued that it is hard to get a true 'vectorized' solution because the bins (or groups) differ in size.  Where you just want one index, @Divikar has given a `searchsorted` solution, [Retrieve indexes of multiple values with Numpy in a vectorization way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49067127)

Comment: @hpaulj the [python wrapper](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/groupby.py#L354) basically builds an iterator of (key, array) pairs.  It does make [cython](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/groupby.pyx) calls for some of the actual computations

Comment: Is `groups` always an array of `uint`s?

Comment: Yes, always 1d unsigned uint8 to be specific @DanielF  (But not guaranteed to be sorted)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a more flexible implementation of `groupby` that can group using any of `numpy`'s `ufunc`s:

```
def groupby_np(X, groups, axis = 0, uf = np.add, out = None, minlength = 0, identity = None):
    if minlength < groups.max() + 1:
        minlength = groups.max() + 1
    if identity is None:
        identity = uf.identity
    i = list(range(X.ndim))
    del i[axis]
    i = tuple(i)
    n = out is None
    if n:
        if identity is None:  # fallback to loops over 0-index for identity
            assert np.all(np.in1d(np.arange(minlength), groups)), "No valid identity for unassinged groups"
            s = [slice(None)] * X.ndim
            for i_ in i:
                s[i_] = 0
            out = np.array([uf.reduce(X[tuple(s)][groups == i]) for i in range(minlength)])
        else:
            out = np.full((minlength,), identity, dtype = X.dtype)
    uf.at(out, groups, uf.reduce(X, i))
    if n:
        return out

groupby_np(X, groups)
array([15, 30])

groupby_np(X, groups, uf = np.multiply)
array([   0, 3024])

groupby_np(X, groups, uf = np.maximum)
array([5, 9])

groupby_np(X, groups, uf = np.minimum)
array([0, 6])
```

Comment: Nice! Just one niggle: The initializer should be settable, you don't want to start - say - multiplication with zero.

Comment: @PaulPanzer, true, it should be `np.full` of `uf.identity`

Comment: `.identity`, huh? Those ufuncs are smarter than I thought

Comment: @PaulPanzer not as smart as I'd hoped.  There's no valid `identity` for `maximum` and `minimum`.  Had to fudge a bit

Comment: This is awesome.  I hate to tack this question on, but I suppose this would preclude `np.mean` given it's not a ufunc?

Comment: True. but you could always do `groupby_np(X, groups)  / groupby_np(np.ones_like(X), groups)`

Answer (score 9):

How about using scipy sparse matrix

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
import time

x_len = 500000
g_len = 100

X = np.arange(x_len * 2).reshape(x_len, 2)
groups = np.random.randint(0, g_len, x_len)

# original
s = time.time()

a = np.array([X[groups==i].sum() for i in np.unique(groups)])

print(time.time() - s)

# using scipy sparse matrix
s = time.time()

x_sum = X.sum(axis=1)
b = np.array(sparse.coo_matrix(
    (
        x_sum,
        (groups, np.arange(len(x_sum)))
    ),
    shape=(g_len, x_len)
).sum(axis=1)).ravel()

print(time.time() - s)

#compare
print(np.abs((a-b)).sum())
```

result on my PC

```
0.15915322303771973
0.012875080108642578
0
```

More than 10 times faster.

---

Update!

Let's benchmark answers of @Paul Panzer and @Daniel F. It is summation only benchmark.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
import time

# by @Daniel F
def groupby_np(X, groups, axis = 0, uf = np.add, out = None, minlength = 0, identity = None):
    if minlength < groups.max() + 1:
        minlength = groups.max() + 1
    if identity is None:
        identity = uf.identity
    i = list(range(X.ndim))
    del i[axis]
    i = tuple(i)
    n = out is None
    if n:
        if identity is None:  # fallback to loops over 0-index for identity
            assert np.all(np.in1d(np.arange(minlength), groups)), "No valid identity for unassinged groups"
            s = [slice(None)] * X.ndim
            for i_ in i:
                s[i_] = 0
            out = np.array([uf.reduce(X[tuple(s)][groups == i]) for i in range(minlength)])
        else:
            out = np.full((minlength,), identity, dtype = X.dtype)
    uf.at(out, groups, uf.reduce(X, i))
    if n:
        return out

x_len = 500000
g_len = 200

X = np.arange(x_len * 2).reshape(x_len, 2)
groups = np.random.randint(0, g_len, x_len)

print("original")
s = time.time()

a = np.array([X[groups==i].sum() for i in np.unique(groups)])

print(time.time() - s)

print("use scipy coo matrix")
s = time.time()

x_sum = X.sum(axis=1)
b = np.array(sparse.coo_matrix(
    (
        x_sum,
        (groups, np.arange(len(x_sum)))
    ),
    shape=(g_len, x_len)
).sum(axis=1)).ravel()

print(time.time() - s)

#compare
print(np.abs((a-b)).sum())


print("use scipy csr matrix @Daniel F")
s = time.time()
x_sum = X.sum(axis=1)
c = np.array(sparse.csr_matrix(
    (
        x_sum,
        groups,
        np.arange(len(groups)+1)
    ),
    shape=(len(groups), g_len)
).sum(axis=0)).ravel()

print(time.time() - s)

#compare
print(np.abs((a-c)).sum())


print("use bincount @Paul Panzer @Daniel F")
s = time.time()
d = np.bincount(groups, X.sum(axis=1), g_len)
print(time.time() - s)

#compare
print(np.abs((a-d)).sum())

print("use ufunc @Daniel F")
s = time.time()
e = groupby_np(X, groups)
print(time.time() - s)

#compare
print(np.abs((a-e)).sum())
```

STDOUT

```
original
0.2882847785949707
use scipy coo matrix
0.012301445007324219
0
use scipy csr matrix @Daniel F
0.01046299934387207
0
use bincount @Paul Panzer @Daniel F
0.007468223571777344
0.0
use ufunc @Daniel F
0.04431319236755371
0
```

The winner is the bincount solution. But the csr matrix solution is also very interesting.

Comment: still slower than `np.bincount(groups, X.sum(axis=1), g_len)` ;-D Still, sparse matrix is a good idea (+1)

Comment: Fast, not very flexible beyond `.sum`

Answer (score 6):

@klim's sparse matrix solution would at first sight appear to be tied to summation. We can, however, use it in the general case by converting between the `csr` and `csc` formats:

Let's look at a small example:

```
>>> m, n = 3, 8                                                                                                     
>>> idx = np.random.randint(0, m, (n,))
>>> data = np.arange(n)
>>>                                                                                                                 
>>> M = sparse.csr_matrix((data, idx, np.arange(n+1)), (n, m))                                                      
>>>                                                                                                                 
>>> idx                                                                                                             
array([0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0])                                                                                     
>>> 
>>> M = M.tocsc()
>>> 
>>> M.indptr, M.indices
(array([0, 2, 4, 8], dtype=int32), array([0, 7, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 6], dtype=int32))
```

As we can see after conversion the internal representation of the sparse matrix yields the indices grouped and sorted:

```
>>> groups = np.split(M.indices, M.indptr[1:-1])
>>> groups
[array([0, 7], dtype=int32), array([3, 4], dtype=int32), array([1, 2, 5, 6], dtype=int32)]
>>>
```

We could have obtained the same using a stable `argsort`:

```
>>> np.argsort(idx, kind='mergesort')
array([0, 7, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 6])
>>>
```

But sparse matrices are actually faster, even when we allow `argsort` to use a faster non-stable algorithm:

```
>>> m, n = 1000, 100000
>>> idx = np.random.randint(0, m, (n,))
>>> data = np.arange(n)
>>> 
>>> timeit('sparse.csr_matrix((data, idx, np.arange(n+1)), (n, m)).tocsc()', **kwds)
2.250748165184632
>>> timeit('np.argsort(idx)', **kwds)
5.783584725111723
```

If we require `argsort` to keep groups sorted, the difference is even larger:

```
>>> timeit('np.argsort(idx, kind="mergesort")', **kwds)
10.507467685034499
```

Comment: This does constrain `data` to be 1d though, no?  I.e. the trick with summing is that it reduced in the input dimensionality from 2 to 1 in this case.  Please let me know if I'm wrong on that.  In the case of something like zero-axis mean on X, it seems you're stuck with 2d

Comment: @BradSolomon If you want to have `data` in the sparse matrix `M`, yes. But that is not strictly necessary. One can keep `data` separately (and put some dummy for `M`s values) and then fancy index them with `M.indices`. In that case `data` can have more dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

There's probably a faster way than this (both of the operands are making copies right now), but:

```
np.bincount(np.broadcast_to(groups, X.T.shape).ravel(), X.T.ravel())

array([ 15.,  30.])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend the answer to a **ndarray**, and still have a fast computation, you could extend the Daniel's solution :

```
x_len = 500000
g_len = 200
y_len = 2

X = np.arange(x_len * y_len).reshape(x_len, y_len)
groups = np.random.randint(0, g_len, x_len)

# original
a = np.array([X[groups==i].sum(axis=0) for i in np.unique(groups)])

# alternative
bins = [0] + list(np.bincount(groups, minlength=g_len).cumsum())
Z = np.argsort(groups)
d = np.array([X.take(Z[bins[i]:bins[i+1]],0).sum(axis=0) for i in range(g_len)])
```

It took about 30 ms (15ms for creating bins + 15ms for summing) instead of 280 ms on the original way in this example.

```
d.shape
>>> (1000, 2)
```