# How to get a sorted cumulative array of values in numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following numpy arrays (which are actually a pandas column) which represent observations (a position and a value):

```
df['x'] = np.array([1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
df['y'] = np.array([2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2])
```

And instead, I would like to get the following two arrays:

```
[1 2 3 4 5]
[4 3 2 3 2]
```

Which is basically grouping all items with the same value in df['x'] and getting the cumulative sum of each value in df['y'], (or in other words getting the cumulative sum of values for each individual position).

Which is the most straightforward way to achieve that in numpy?

Comment: since they are in a dataframe, i think you can just do `df.groupby('x', as_index=False)['y'].sum()`

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use pandas for this?

Comment: Thanks, Is there any way to do it purely in numpy?

Comment: You can just export the result in numpy or you want to specifically do all of this in numpy?

Comment: I am curious to understand -for learning purposes- how this could be done -if there is such option- purely in numpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have noted in comments, if you're already using pandas it's probably a good idea to use a sum over groupby. That being said, if you insist on using raw NumPy you can find the unique indices of `x` and then sum up corresponding values in `y` in an accumulator array:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y = np.array([2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2])

vals, inds = np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)
res = np.zeros_like(vals, dtype=y.dtype)
np.add.at(res, inds, y)

print(res)
# [4 3 2 3 2]
```

`vals` are the unique values in `x` and are not actually used here. `inds` is the key: these are the index of each value of `x` in `vals`. These are the positions in the result where we want to accumulate corresponding values from `y`. The last trick is using [`np.add.at`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) for an unbuffered summation.

The result is stored in `res`.

Answer (score 1):

We can try

```
def groupby(a, b):
    sidx = b.argsort(kind='mergesort')
    a_sorted = a[sidx]
    b_sorted = b[sidx]
    cut_idx = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True,b_sorted[1:] != b_sorted[:-1],True])
    out = [sum(a_sorted[i:j]) for i,j in zip(cut_idx[:-1],cut_idx[1:])]
    return out


groupby(df['y'].values,df['x'].values)
Out[223]: [4, 3, 2, 3, 2]
```

Notice the original function you can refer to Divakar 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49373017/7964527) (Thanks Divakar again :-), for teaching me bumpy)