# Create unique row in 2D numpy array by adding corresponding values

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a 2-dimensional numpy array in python:

```
[[ 1  2  1  3  3]
 [10 20 30 40 60]]
```

I would like to have **unique values in the first row** and **adding the corresponding values in the second row** together before deleting the columns. So, the output for my array would be this:

```
[[  1   2   3 ]
 [ 40  20 100 ]]
```

I'm a newbie to python and I can't think of efficient way doing this for larger scales.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `numpy` doesn't have a built-in groupby function (though there are [ways to write them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49141969/vectorized-groupby-with-numpy)). If you're open to using `pandas`, this would be straightforward:

```
import pandas as pd

>>> pd.DataFrame(a.T).groupby(0,as_index=False).sum().values.T

array([[  1,   2,   3],
       [ 40,  20, 100]])
```

Comment: Instead of transposing: `pd.DataFrame(a[1:], columns=a[0]).groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum().values`

Answer (score 0):

```
a = np.array([[ 1,  2,  1,  3,  3],
              [10, 20, 30, 40, 60]])

unique_values = np.unique(a[0])
new_array = np.zeros((2, len(unique_values)))
for i, uniq in enumerate(np.unique(a[0])):

    new_array[0][i] = uniq
    new_array[1][i] = np.where(a[0]==uniq,a[1],0).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll get much more efficient than using a dictionary for the counts and then creating the array from that:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy

sums = defaultdict(float)

arr = numpy.array([[ 1,  2,  1,  3,  3],
                   [10, 20, 30, 40, 60]]

for key, value in zip(*arr):
    sums[key] += value


numpy.array(list(sums.items())).T
```

returns

```
array([[  1.,   2.,   3.],
       [ 40.,  20., 100.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `sparse.csr_matrix`:

```
from scipy import sparse
b = a[0]
v = a[1]
m = b.max() + 1
s = v.shape[0]

res = sparse.csr_matrix((v, b, np.arange(s+1)), (s, m)).sum(0)
```

```
matrix([[  0,  40,  20, 100]], dtype=int32)
```

---

This shows the sum of every value from `0-a[0].max()` in this case, so to link it back to your initial result:

```
t = np.unique(a[0])
np.stack((t, res.A1[t]))
```

```
array([[  1,   2,   3],
       [ 40,  20, 100]])
```