# np keep rows contain specific value python

Tags: python, numpy, conditional-statements, rows

I have a 2D `numpy` array, how can I keep only rows that contain a specific value, and then flatten the array keeping only unique values.

```
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 4],
       [3, 5],
       [4, 6],
       [5, 7]])
```

If I need to keep only rows containing `2`, I expect the result `([0,2,4])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could use:

```
np.unique(a[(a==2).any(1)].ravel())
```

output: `array([0, 2, 4])`

##### using pandas

this is both faster and not sorting the data

```
import pandas as pd
pd.unique(a[(a==2).any(1)].ravel())
```

output: `array([0, 2, 4])`

*credit to @MichaelSzczesny*

Comment: If order doesn't matter.

Comment: Correct @Michael

Comment: `pd.unique(a[(a == 2).any(1)].ravel())`, is faster (no sorting) and preserves order. But you have to import `pandas`. I would really like to have this option in `numpy`.

Comment: @Michael I agree, while `numpy` is usually faster, there are sometimes nice methods in pandas. I also would love a numpy `groupby` ;)

Comment: @mozway [I've tried before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49146228/4427777), but it's pretty hacky.

Comment: @DanielF yes, that's why a native function would be great